# Instalar SSL a un Docker con proxy NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

Hola qué tal? tengo un servidor Ubuntu que tengo dentro un tiledesk-server, con docker-compose
el proyecto manipula las conexiones a través de nginx
https://github.com/Tiledesk/tiledesk-docker-proxy/blob/master/nginx.conf
el código es el siguiente:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    
  resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
  }
  server {
        listen 80;
        location / {       
            return 301 $scheme://$host/dashboard/;
        }
        location /dashboard/ {
            proxy_pass http://dashboard:80/;
        }
        location /chat/ {
            proxy_pass http://ionic:80/;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://server:3000/;
        }     
        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://server:3000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
        location /config.json {
            proxy_pass http://server:3000/chat21/config;
        }    
        location /widget/ {
            proxy_pass http://webwidget:80/;
        }     
        location /widget-config.json {
            proxy_pass http://webwidget:80/widget-config.json;
        }
     
       
       
      
  }
}
```

Y quisiera que se ejecute un subdominio que está redireccionado la IP publica de este servidor, llevara HTTPS puerto 445 con un certificado SSL autorenovable.
Yo puedo crear un certificado con nginx SSL común y corriente. El problema esta que los puertos 80 están utilizados por el Docker que contiene este nginx
Debería editar el nginx de este Docker? sería muy complicado porque tengo que agregar el certificado al Docker, y tengo que rediseñar todo el Docker, sería más sencillo correr el nginx fuera del Docker, pero al estar ocupado el puerto 80 no puedo iniciarlo. ¿Cuál sería la solución? alguien la ve?
PD: el docker-compose utiliza ya puertos 80

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
87da1472e819        tiledesk/tiledesk-docker-proxy    "nginx-debug -g 'dae…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       tiledesk-docker-proxy
55c7e06a09a3        tiledesk/tiledesk-server          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   tiledesk-server
9275e2512888        tiledesk/tiledesk-dashboard       "/bin/sh -c 'envsubs…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:4500->80/tcp     tiledesk-dashboard
423de97344fc        chat21/chat21-web-widget:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'envsubs…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:4200->80/tcp     chat21-web-widget
7e9618e7c897        chat21/chat21-ionic               "/bin/sh -c 'envsubs…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp     chat21-ionic
c964df8642af        mongo                             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 hours ago        Up 2 hours          27017/tcp                mongo
a3aee6a19cb0        wernight/ngrok                    "ngrok http server:3…"   15 hours ago        Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:4040->4040/tcp   ngrok
```

Comment: cambia el puerto 80 del docker, como por ejemplo 3000 y y cuando entren con el 80 de la ip externa tu lo cambias al 3000 por la interna (proxy pass) o creas una redes en docker para esto esta ultima me parece mas complicada

Comment: tambien utiliza algunos dockers, los puertos 80 acabo de agregarlo...

Comment: nginx usa el puerto 80 otra cosa es cual es el puerto de salida de tu docker puedes configurar ese puerto

Comment: mira la respuesta estan los puertos que utiliza

Comment: @JackNavaRow cono cambio el puerto del docker??

Comment: mira la [documentacion!](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) basicamente es ejecutar el comando algo como `docker run --name some-nginx -d -p 8080:80 some-content-nginx`